# Best practice for choosing nested resources in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

What criteria do you use to decide whether or not to nest resources?

In the past, I have chosen to nest when the index action on a resource makes no sense without scoping to an associated resource (the parent).

Even as I write the above criteria, I realize it is ambiguous at best.

A colleague has stated:

> Nest resources because it captures the relationship of the associated models visually in the url structure...  And it makes it easy to modify the url to get back to just the post.  If I see /posts/123/offers/555  -- I know that I can go to /posts/123 to see my post.   Where as if I just saw /offers/555, I'd have no way to get back to the post other than manually navigating through the site.

To me, manipulation of the url by users should have no bearing on the architecture of the application, and flies against what I understand to be the generally held principle that nested resources should be avoided if at all possible. Additionally, this argument would seem to support multiple levels of nesting, which again, pretty much every article I read advises against.

What has been your experience?

Answer (score 0):

I nest routes, as you put it first, when the later things in the route doesn't make sense without the former. Comments on a blog would be nested under `resources articles` because, though perhaps you want display an individual comment on it's own page (who knows why...), a comment belongs to an article.

This also has controller implementations. If you know the article, then you can find the specific comment scoped to the article. This makes for more effective queries.

Also, your colleague was correct that you have to deal with users messing around with your routes, though he had the wrong reason. It isn't for their convenience, but for their security.

Let's take an Amazon-like app with users and orders. If I am at `users/5/orders/2` then I think "hey! I can just change that 5 to a 4 and then see someone else's orders!" If you don't scope orders, then the controller-level logic for authorizing a user to view `orders/2` becomes far trickier. Scoping to the user allows for `current_user.orders.find(params[:id])` in the orders controller. Current user can be found based on authentication so that they cannot just swap ids in the URL and become someone else.

Comment: Your Amazon-like example doesn't really illustrate the value of a nested route.  If you are doing current_user.orders then the "users/5" in users/5/orders/2 is completely superfluous.  So I don't really see how that's an example of security.  /orders/2 could be doing the exact same thing:  current_user.orders.find(params[:id]) ...  So I don't quite get the point.  I am more apt to feel like this is an example where nesting routes is not appropriate because it has no value at all.